Script to paste flip all actions?
So I have an armature with flipped animations. Copy and paste flipped (SHIFT+CTRL+V) works fine but it's kind of tedious to manually do it for every action. I've been thinking of making a script that automates all of this process but the problem is, the action still remains the same instead of flipping. I even checked to see if all of the actions were being iterated and sure enough, they were. This is the code I have, I apologize if it seems very basic as I am completely new to Python and the Blender API.
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
obj = bpy.context.object

for a in bpy.data.actions:
    obj.animation_data.action = a
    bpy.ops.pose.copy()
    bpy.ops.pose.paste(flipped=True)
    

I'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong. Is there a way to go around this? Thanks in advance.

The thing about using operators themselves is that they are dependent on the context they're used in. So it's expecting you to have an action selected and active in the correct viewport to work correctly. I haven't tested it but more than likely what's happening is you aren't adjusting the context for each action, so you're just running the same bpy.ops.pose.paste()over and over for every action in the bpy.data.actions list. More about this topic here.

Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to get it to adjust the context for each action then? Or would it be just better to go for another approach? Maybe involving fcurves?

Operators in bpy.ops are for interactive use through the UI and should be avoided in scripts because they depend on context. Using them through scripts may yield unexpected results at best, or fail entirely at worst. Manipulate data directly from bpy.data instead.

On modern version of Blender you can override context. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add

So after some tinkering, I've managed to come up with this code:
import bpy
source_obj = bpy.context.active_object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
for actions in bpy.data.actions:
    source_obj.animation_data.action = bpy.data.actions[actions.name]   
    frame_start,frame_end =map(int,source_obj.animation_data.action.frame_range)
    for i in range(1,frame_end+1):
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(i)
        bpy.ops.pose.copy()
        bpy.ops.pose.paste(flipped=True)
        bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert()
        bpy.context.view_layer.update()

It's most likely not the best code to go around to doing what I originally wanted, but it does what I need.
